# Push comma delimited string to array with key value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push a comma delimited string into an array with key+value.

```
"one, two, three"
```

to

```
[{ text: 'one' }, { text: 'two' },{ text: 'three' }]
```

**JS** Not working

```js
_RA = "one, two, three";

var stringArray = new Array();
var tagsArray = new Array();
stringArray = _RA.split(",");

for (var x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj['text'] = stringArray[x];
  tagsArray.push(obj);
};

console.log(tagsArray);
```

Comment: Are you sure? My output is `[ { text: 'one' }, { text: 'two' }, { text: 'three' } ]` using your above code and the input of `"one,two,three"` (notice the lack of spaces)

Comment: Please add more information (or a [mvce] that shows the actual problem) because your code works.

Comment: the output of your code matches the expected output, except for some leading spaces which you can remove from _RA - so the problem is something else

Comment: @GalAbra Why did you add the spaces in `_RA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was almost working. I only added a `const` on the first line and removed all the spaces from `_RA`.

```js
const _RA = "one, two, three"; // Added 'const' here
var stringArray = new Array();
var tagsArray = new Array();
stringArray = _RA.replace(/ /g, "").split(","); // Added the 'replace' method
for (var x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj['text'] = stringArray[x];
  tagsArray.push(obj);
};

console.log(tagsArray);
```

Comment: _"Your code was almost working"_ - Even better, it already worked so why the "answer"? Adding `const` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
let _RA = "one, two, three";

let tagsArray = _RA.split(/,\s*/).map(s=>({text:s}))

console.log(tagsArray);
```

These codes will make better.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = 'one,two,three';
let result = arr.split(',').map((i) => {
return {text: i}
})
console.log(result)
```